# Is there a NuGet way to upgrade a version of a transitive dependency besides defining a direct dependency?

Tags: gradle, nuget, dependency-management

Assuming for some reason I need to upgrade a transient dependency in NuGet (bugfix, vulnerability, etc.), is there a way to upgrade it without adding a direct dependency (which is wrong conceptually and may cause conflicts down the road)?

Something equivalent to the Gradle option: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html

Link to github ticket: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12579

Comment: Pretty certain this isn't a thing in NuGet, you just have to add a direct dep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify transitive dependency versions using [transitive pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/Central-Package-Management#transitive-pinning).

Notice that currently you need to enable this feature before use.